# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not find service named in wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf, tomcat7

I  use CXF 2.7 and tomcat 7.
I have create a web project with eclipse Juno that expose some web services.
After deployment on tomcat i get wsdl from browser and all looks fine.

Then i create a second web project that is the consumer and i deploy it on tomcat. 
When i try to call any web service from consumer i get the following error:

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not find service named {http://service.example.com/}UserSrvImpl in wsdl http://x.x.x.x:8088/TaxisNetTestUI/services/UserSrvImplPort?wsdl

My service call example is:

```
UserSrvImpl service = new UserSrvImpl();
UserSrvImplPortType client = service.getUserSrvImplPort();
client.register(ObjetValue);
```

What going wrong ?

My wsdl is:
[WSDL FILE](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxuK2FNeTzsdeDJaSVQ2RHg2YnM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create again the web services, but this time i create manually my interface. I create a class that iplements this interface and then i create the web service and all works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need

```
UserSrv service = new UserSrvImpl();
UserSrvImplPortType client = service.getUserSrvImplPort();
client.register(ObjetValue);
```

Use interfase instead of implementation class as link